# How to detect when Player Sprite is not colliding with a collision

Tags: phaser-framework

My `handleCollider` runs whenever my player collides with my `collisionLayer`

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import Player from '@/players/Player'
import { CustomCursorKeys, Direction } from '@/types/phaser'

export default class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  public cursors: CustomCursorKeys | null = null
  public player: Player | null = null

  constructor(key: string) {
    super(key)
  }

  handleCollider(player: Player | null) {
    if (player){
      player.hasPlayerCollided = true
    }
  }

  create(param: { 
    map: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap, 
    x: number, 
    y: number,
    direction: Direction  
  }) {
    // Set up collisions
    const collisionTileset = param.map.addTilesetImage('Collision_48x48', 'collision')
    const collisionLayer = param.map.createLayer('Collisions', collisionTileset)
    collisionLayer.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true })

    // Set up cursor keys for player movement
    this.cursors = {
      ...this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys(),
      ...(this.input.keyboard.addKeys('W,S,A,D')),
    }

    // Create player sprite and add physics
    this.player = this.add.player(param.x, param.y, param.direction, '')

    // Create player collision
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, collisionLayer, () => this.handleCollider(this.player))
  }
}
```

But I need to reset `player.hasPlayerCollided` to be `false` when my player is NOT colliding with my collisionLayer. Otherwise my `hasPlayerCollided` will always be `true` after my player collides once. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your game and you performance needs, you could:

*(here some from the top of my head, have to test them still in code to 100% confirm they work)*

1. if you are only colliding with the `collisionLayer` you could, simply use the property blocked on the `player.body`.

   ```
   if(player.hasPlayerCollided && player.body.blocked.none){
       player.hasPlayerCollided = false;
   }
   ```

   *(Yes one could do this in one line, but I don't know all the edge case so better save than sorry)*
2. set `player.hasPlayerCollided` to `false` at the end of the `update` function. *(quick and dirt solution)*

**Here a short demo, showing both solutions in one:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:10px;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 218 ,
    height: 70,
    zoom: 2,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity: { y: 50 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

var cursors;
var player;
var playerStateText;
const SPEED = 50;

var isJumping = true;
var isColliding = false;

function create () {
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(16, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(24, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tiles', 8*4, 8);

    let level = [
      [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    ];

    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    layer.setCollisionBetween(1,3);
    
    this.player = this.add.circle(16, 16, 6, 0xffffff)
        .setDepth(2);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(this.player);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(layer, this.player, function(player, tile){
        isJumping = false;
        isColliding = true;
    });
    
    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    
    this.message = this.add.text(10,10, '')
      .setFontSize(10);
}

function setText(scene, player){
  scene.message.setText(`is Colliding: ${isColliding}\nPlayer blocked: ${!player.body.blocked.none}`)
}

function update(){
  
  if(this.keys.left.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(-SPEED);
  }else if(this.keys.right.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(SPEED);
  } else {
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(0);
  }
  
  if (!isJumping && this.keys.up.isDown){
      this.player.body.setVelocityY(-SPEED * .75);
      isJumping = true;
  } 
  
  setText(this, this.player);
  isColliding = false;
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
Use Arrow-Key to move the player</span><br>
```

Comment: @dev_el your welcome. I always want to be sure, that my answers are as accurate as possible, and prevent misunderstandings. And I also like coding ;-) And thank you for your kind feedback.